# Does SAS have a concurrency framework like Java

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, sas

In Java,you have a concurrency framework that the developer can use to submit multiple tasks in parallel where each task runs in its own thread.

Does a similar concurrency framework exist in SAS where developer can submit parallel jobs or programs in different threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With SAS, there are (as there always are) myriad ways to do what you ask.

The closest thing to exactly what you ask for is [SAS MP Connect](http://support.sas.com/rnd/scalability/connect/mp.html), a system for allowing multiple threads either on a SMP ([symmetric multiprocessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_multiprocessing)) machine.  It's a part of SAS/Connect starting in version 8.

If you are submitting code (via SAS/Connect) to a server, you have other options.  You can submit multiple queries with `rsubmit` using either synchronous or asynchronous processing, for example.

You can also, of course, submit multiple SAS calls yourself, if you don't have a license for SAS/CONNECT.  You can either have a batch process that calls multiple SAS sessions with different input parameters, or have SAS itself call more copies of itself (recursively, perhaps).

If you have SAS 9.4, you can also use [PROC DS2](http://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2014/BI/MWSUG-2014-BI17.pdf), which has built-in multithreading.  It is a more object-oriented approach to SAS data processing, and operates natively with threads.

[Some people have also done their own custom multithreading, of course](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/109-2010.pdf).

There is also the possibility of [running code in Java from SAS.](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/241-30.pdf)

If you're running [SAS Grid computing](http://support.sas.com/rnd/scalability/grid/), that has a great deal of capabilities in this area as well.

SAS happily works with Teradata, Hadoop, and many other database providers and database-like providers, which have significant capabilities for in-database processing that is often multithreaded.

Finally, there is the possibility that SAS [already multithreads the procs you're using](http://support.sas.com/rnd/scalability/procs/) automatically.  In fact, odds are this is where your best performance improves will lie; SAS does a very good job optimizing these procedures, and often an improvement can be made simply using them.